# Cannot login to Solaris due to chown on /usr directory

Tags: unix, solaris, chown

Someone ran "chown -R username /usr" and now I have no way of logging into the box to change it back.  SSH has been disabled, X Server won't start so I have no graphical GUI, and the console login keeps saying "Login Incorrect" when I try to login.  I don't have the exact message next to me, but it says some files within the /usr directory are not owned by root, which leads me to believe the chown was the problem that caused this.

I can change the ownership back if I can just get into the command prompt somehow.  Does anyone have any ideas how I could get a command prompt from this?

The box is a Dell T310 server running Solaris 10 (10/09 version).